# Best way to create an executable for a Gem using Rake

Tags: ruby, rake, rubygems

What is the best way to create an executable (a file in the `bin/` directory) for a Gem using Rake? I have a gem that I want to make an executable for and I'm not quite sure how to actually create the executable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You shouldn't need to generate your gem's executables. Ideally, your executable depends upon the library that your gem provides for functionality. For example, take a look at [the `heroku` executable in the Heroku gem](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/bin/heroku#files):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

lib = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib')
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) if File.directory?(lib) && !$LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)

require 'heroku'
require 'heroku/command'

args = ARGV.dup
ARGV.clear
command = args.shift.strip rescue 'help'

Heroku::Command.run(command, args)
```

It's the minimum amount of code necessary to parse the command line and ship that data off to the rest of the Heroku library for processing. No need for generating anything when the code changes, because the executable itself depends on the code to function.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create the executable using ruby, the keyword you're looking for is [`Shebang`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

Simply create a file (bin/yourexecutable), drop the ".rb" extension if you want, add the [`Shebang`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) on top, using `/usr/bin/env ruby` and have at it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "hello world"
```

Give it an executable flag via `chmod +x bin/yourexecutable` and you can launch it by calling it directly.

```
varar:~ mr$ bin/yourexecutable
hello world
varar:~ mr$
```

Check the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Portability) for more info.

Obviously, this won't work on Windows.

Comment: I'm aware of the hashbang, I just want to know the best way to create this with Rake.

Comment: Is there a reason you're insisting on using Rake? You can create the file, make it executable, and edit it with `touch bin/yourexecutable && chmod +x bin/yourexecutable && my_editor bin/yourexecutable`

Comment: @BrandonTilley: Yes, I am going to be building the gem with Rake, and I think it would be easier to use Rake for building the gem and for making the executable. I think it would be faster to automate the process with Rake.

Comment: @Mark But you'll only need to create the executable once, correct? It should never change (other than big library changes). Generally you write it to work with your gem's library. [Heroku's executable is a great example](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/bin/heroku#files)--it gathers info from the command line and passes it on to the library, no need to "generate it."

Comment: Unless you're referring to "how do I create it on the machine of someone who installs my gem", in which case [your gemspec should handle it for you](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/heroku.gemspec#L13).

Comment: @BrandonTilley: Well, during development, it *will* change, correct? As I change the Ruby code, the executable should change as well, right? Also, I'll be in the chat (Ruby/Rails room) to carry this conversation on if need be.